# Cell Flash on Specific Value

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need a cell that flashes on edit only when a specific word, for example  "WINNER" , is the value entered (Currently Cells word is populated via an If statement).  Have tried modifying the scripting along the lines of :
    `if( activeCell == "A1"="WINNER" )` but to no avail.

Below is the link to the test sheet.

[Flashing Cell](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1RmVEezxZHNr1v6PlZd2xpF6utI2sVp9siNs0A9pz1ew/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Thanks guys. Both work but not as expected. Thought it might be a little simpler like just an extra line of code. As you mentioned a trigger is required as the cell change by formula wont trigger the event.

Answer (score 0):

How about this sample? If it doesn't work of blink, installing trigger may be necessary for it.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  if (e.value == "WINNER") {
    var number = 5; // Number of blink
    for (var i = 0; i < number * 2; i++) {
      if (i % 2 == 0) {
        var color = "white";
      } else {
        var color = "red";
      }
      e.range.setBackground(color);
      SpreadsheetApp.flush();
      Utilities.sleep(300); // Blink speed (ms)
    }
    e.range.setBackground("white") // Cell color is white after blinks were completed.
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the best way to do it.  I'm sure Google would frown upon me for my poor usage of cpu time.  But here it is anyway.

```
function flash()
{
  var sht = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var cell = sht.getActiveCell();
  var i = 0;
  var j = 0;
  while(j < 10)//It flashes the active cell for a few seconds
  {
    cell.setBackground('red');
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();//If you don't do the first it won't flash.
    while(i < 100000){i++;}
    i = 0;
    cell.setBackground('white')
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    while(i < 100000){i++}
    i = 0;
  j++
  }

}
```